# Same ID error in TreeList

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, treelist

I am using `TreeList` of DevExpress with C#. I have some scenario like this, I have 2 tables. `Table # 1` contains directory info and `Table # 2` contains files info. Column named `Parent` is directory in which the directory/file is placed.

```
Folder Table
ID  Parent  Name
1     1     Folder1
2     1     Folder2
3     2     Folder3

File Table
ID   Parent   Name
1      1      file1.txt
2      2      file2.txt
3      2      file3.txt
```

I am storing both tables in `dt`

```
DataTable dt
ID  Parent  Name
1      1    Folder1
2      1    Folder2
3      2    Folder3
1      1    file1.txt
2      2    file2.txt
3      2    file3.txt
```

and doing something like this

```
treelist.datasource = dt;
treelist.parentfieldname = "Parent";
```

I want to show both files and folder in `treelist`. This is not working as I have same ID of file and folder. Can anyone suggest any simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quick and easy solution, i added column in `dt`

```
Folder Table
ID    Parent  Name
1       1     Folder1
2       1     Folder2
3       2     Folder3

File Table
ID    Parent   Name
4       1      file1.txt
5       2      file2.txt
6       2      file3.txt
```

merged both tables in `dt`

```
DataTable
ID    OrigID   Parent  Name
1        1       1     Folder1
2        2       1     Folder2
3        3       2     Folder3
4        1       1     file1.txt
5        2       2     file2.txt
6        3       2     file3.txt
```

wrote same following lines

```
treelist.datasource = dt;
treelist.parentfieldname = "Parent";
```

Problem Solved!

Answer (score 1):

I believe, in this case you should implement [dynamical data loading](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5560) instead of using [bound mode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5555) to manually resolve files/folders relationship.

Related links:
  [How to: Load Data Dynamically via Events](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5562)
  [Tree Generation Algorithm in the XtraTreeList](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument198)

Comment: `Tree Generation Algorithm in the XtraTreeList` works for single table but not multiple tables as your id gets same. I think i should now manually create treelist and should not give it as datasource

Comment: @AndroidLearner: I've mentioned the same idea above: the bound mode does not work in this case because this is "generation algorithm" specific, thus you should use "dynamical loading"

Comment: i have to load data from table, not from directory. What i am loading in tree is not file and folder i only mentioned this scenario as its simple to understand.

Comment: @AndroidLearner: The main idea of "dynamical loading" is - you can provide any data from any table via special events. The sample is demonstrates it using a files. You can adapt this sample for your datatables.